# Auto-forwarding telegram message if channel owner intercepts it with hidden text preventing a copy

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I am trying to autforward a message from a certain channel with a script below and it works for 99% of channels I am indenting to use this one on however there is one channel that instead of forwarding the message I want to copy picks up some invisible message on the channel.

I am 100% certain I have chat IDs correct and I have tried going around hidden characters but nothing works.

Has anybody dealt with this in the past?

Please see couple of scripts I tried below -

SCRIPT A

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, events

# Your credentials
api_id = "X"
api_hash = 'Y'
phone_number = 'Z'

# Source and destination pair of channels/groups
chat_mapping = {
    -A: -B,
}

client = TelegramClient(phone_number, api_id, api_hash)

@client.on(events.NewMessage(chats=list(chat_mapping.keys())))
async def handler(event):
    dest_id = chat_mapping.get(event.chat_id)
    if dest_id:
        if event.message.photo or event.message.document:
            # Forwarding media as it is
            await client.send_file(dest_id, event.message.media)
        elif event.message.text:
            # Forwarding text
            await client.send_message(dest_id, event.message.text)
        # Add more conditions here for other types like stickers, video, etc.

with client:
    client.start()
    print("Client is running. Listening for messages...")
    client.run_until_disconnected()


I also tried variation with below. I tried few more variations and even consulted chat GPT lol.
"await app.send_message(dest_id, message.text)"
```